# Set unique value dynamically without loop using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to join a table to itself on either of two values. I can do this easily enough with an `OR` in the join. However, I am trying to create a table to house this data to make it easier as I add new records daily. I want to create a table to hold this data, and keep a unique value for each result.

I have a working example below, but it uses a `while` loop and is extremely slow. I would like to convert this to a *set-based* operation, but keep coming up short.

Table `@t` is the source of the data. Table `@hh` is the new table to hold the unique value (`hhid`).

Example:

```
declare @t table (appid int, phone varchar(10), bcn varchar(10));
declare @hh table (bcn varchar(10), hhid int default(null));

insert @t 
      select 1, '1115551212','1'
union select 2, '1115551212','1'
union select 3, '1115551212','2'
union select 4, '9995551212','2'
union select 5, '8885551212','3'
union select 6, '1115551212','4'
union select 7, '1115551212','5'
union select 8, '7775551212','1'
union select 9, '7785551212','6'
union select 10, '7795551212','6'

insert @hh select distinct bcn,null from @t;

DECLARE @hhid int = -1;
DECLARE @bcn varchar(10);

SELECT TOP(1) @bcn =  bcn FROM @hh WHERE hhid is null;
SELECT @hhid = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(isnull(hhid,-1)) FROM @hh),-1);
if @hhid = -1
        SET @hhid = 4999999;
WHILE @bcn is not null
BEGIN
    SET @hhid += 1;

    UPDATE @hh SET hhid = @hhid WHERE bcn in (
    select distinct t2.bcn
    FROM @hh h
    JOIN @t t on h.bcn = t.bcn
    left join @t t2 on t.phone = t2.phone
    WHERE h.bcn = @bcn and t.phone <> '');

    SET @bcn = null;
    SELECT top(1) @bcn =  bcn from @hh where hhid is null;
END

select * from @hh
```

EDIT:
Expected Results (as returned by the code):

```
BCN  HHID  
 1   5000000  
 2   5000000  
 3   5000001  
 4   5000000  
 5   5000000  
 6   5000002
```

From the output, you can see that all records that share either a BCN or PHONE value get the same HHID, and those that do not share anything in common with others get their own unique ID.  As I said, this code works, and does what I need, but I want to try to replace it with set-based operations.

Comment: Please include your expected results

Comment: I have edited the post to show the expected results.  The table @hh will be used as a lookup, so I comb through all records in @t and match on bcn OR phone, those are like entries, and should share the same hhid value.

Comment: You say _all records that share either a BCN or PHONE value get the same HHID_ but the rows with `appid` = 3 & 4 nave been grouped with `bcn = 1` because the first row processed by your loop matched on `phone`. What happened to the row with `appid = 4`? Shouldn't that have been grouped with `appid = 3` because it matched on `bcn`, creating a new `hhid`? It seems to get lost because of the order in which the data was processed. I think you need to decide which takes precedence, `bcn` _or_ `phone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script does it without loop/cursor. It creates two indexes that are important to speed up the query: `t_phone_ind` and `t_bcn_ind`. You can check the actual execution plan, you'll see they are both being used to speed up the query.

```
CREATE TABLE #t(appid INT PRIMARY KEY, phone VARCHAR(10), bcn VARCHAR(10));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX t_phone_ind ON #t(phone,bcn); -- for bcn->MIN(phone)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX t_bcn_ind ON #t(bcn,phone);   -- for phone->MIN(bcn)
insert #t(appid,phone,bcn) 
      select 1, '1115551212','1'
union select 2, '1115551212','1'
union select 3, '1115551212','2'
union select 4, '9995551212','2'
union select 5, '8885551212','3'
union select 6, '1115551212','4'
union select 7, '1115551212','5'
union select 8, '7775551212','1'
union select 9, '7785551212','6'
union select 10, '7795551212','6';

;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT bcn,MIN(phone) AS phone FROM #t GROUP BY bcn 
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT phone,MIN(bcn) AS bcn FROM #t GROUP BY phone
)
SELECT
    cte1.bcn,
    hhid=4999999+DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cte2.bcn)
FROM
    cte1
    LEFT JOIN cte2 ON
        cte2.phone=cte1.phone
ORDER BY
    cte1.bcn;

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------+
| bcn |  hhid   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | 5000000 |
|   2 | 5000000 |
|   3 | 5000001 |
|   4 | 5000000 |
|   5 | 5000000 |
|   6 | 5000002 |
+-----+---------+
```